# How to convert DataTable to List on runtype with out existing class property?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, reflection

I'm using VS2010 and C#. I have one DataTable which I want to convert to a List.

```
Suppose:
Table dt;
```

On run time want to create similar field from a datatable and fill fields in List.There is no existing class for list properties.

```
ListName=TableName
List property name=Table column name
List Property type=Table column type
List items=Table rows
```

**Note:** Recently work on  EF.To fullfill  my project requirement, need to give flexibility to use to  input and execute ESQL  at runtime .I don’t want to put this execute result on datatable or `List<DataRow>` ,want to put this result on list.
 List has no existing class and property,don’t want to convert DataTable on  list Type:DataRow

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to create a new class at runtime.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: But a List does not have fields.  A List contains strongly typed objects.

Comment: Blam thanks for reply,we can create object on run time,can we not?After create object we can also assign this to list but problem is stuck on this issue,so i seek help.

Comment: The "issue" is so unclear to me.   You ask for List property name Table and List has no property named Table.

Comment: Blam ,List item property names are similar as table column name and property type are column type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are still not sure what are you trying to do, but if you want to create list of dynamic objects, you can try `dynamic`

```
var dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();
```

Then you will have to assign values to that list through `ExpandoObject`

And the you will have to Cast it to `IDictionary` to pass column names as properties.

And then you can access list items like this `item.YourColumnName`

Here's a full example:

```
            var dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col2");
            dt.Rows.Add("val1","val2");
            dt.Rows.Add("val3", "val4");
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dynamic myObj = new ExpandoObject();
                var p = myObj as IDictionary<string, object>;
                p[dr.Table.Columns[0].ColumnName] = dr[0];
                p[dr.Table.Columns[1].ColumnName] = dr[1];
                dynamicList.Add(p);
            }

            foreach (var item in dynamicList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Col1 + " " + item.Col2);
            }
```

or linq also works of course for printing out the values:

```
dynamicList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Col1 + " " + x.Col2));
```

this program will print out:

```
val1 val2
val3 val4
```